# Keep (specific) celery result objects in NoSQL backend for independent usage

Tags: python, mongodb, celery, distributed-computing

This is a rather specific question to advanced users of celery. Let me explain the use case I have:

#### Usecase

I have to run ~1k-100k tasks that will run a simulation (movie) and return the data of the simulation as a rather large list of smaller objects (frames), say 10k-100k per frame and 1k frames. So the total amount of data produced will be very large, but assume that I have a database that can handle this. Speed is not a key factor here. Later I need to compute features from each frame which can be done completely independent.

The frames look like a `dict` that point to some numpy arrays and other simple data like strings and numbers and have a unique identifier UUID.

Important is that the final objects of interest are arbitrary joins and splits of these generated lists. As a metaphor consider the result movies be chop and recombined into new movies. These final lists (movies) are then basically a list of references to the frames using their UUIDs.

Now, I consider using celery to get these first movies and since these will end up in the backend DB anyway I might just keep these results indefinitely, at least the ones I specify to keep.

#### My question

Can I configure a backend, preferably a NonSQL DB, in a way to keep the results and access these later independent from Celery using the objects UUID. And if so does that make sense because of overhead and performance, etc.

Another possibility would be to not return anything and let the worker store the result in a DB. Is that preferred? It seems unnecessary to have a second channel of communication to another DB when Celery can do this already.

I am also interested in comments on using Celery in general for highly independent tasks that run long (>1h) and return large result objects. A fail is not problematic and can just be restarted. The resulting movies are stochastic! so functional approaches can be problematic. Even storing the random seed might not garantuee reproducible results! although I do not have side-effects. I just might have lots of workers available that are widely distributed. Imagine lots of desktop machines in a closed environment where every worker helps even if it is slow. Network speed and security is not an issue here. I know that this is not the original use case, but it seemed very easy to use it for these cases. The best analogy I found are projects like Folding@Home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I configure a backend, preferably a NonSQL DB, in a way to keep the results and access these later independent from Celery using the objects UUID.

Yes, you can configure celery to store its results in a NoSQL database such as redis for access by UUID later.  The two settings that will control the behavior of interest for you are [`result_expires`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#result-expires) and [`result_backend`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#result-backend).

`result_backend` will specify which NoSQL database you want to store your results in (e.g., elasticsearch or redis) while `result_expires` will specify how long after a task completes that the task's result will be available for access.

After the task completes, you can access the results in python like this:

```
from celery.result import AsyncResult
result = task_name.delay()
print result.id
uuid = result.id
checked_result = AsyncResult(uuid)
# and you can access the result output here however you'd like
```

> And if so does that make sense because of overhead and performance, etc.

I think this strategy makes perfect sense.  I have typically used this a number of times when generating long-running reports for web users.  The initial post will return the UUID from the celery task.  The web client can poll the app sever via javascript using the UUID to see if the task is ready/complete.  Once the report is ready, the page can redirect the user to the route that will allow the user to download or view the report by passing in the UUID.